# How to get multiple line between two specific string with regex?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags

I am searching in a huge string with regular expression like that `<Detail>.*?</Detail>`, but this is not giving me any results.

I want to get all multi-line text between these two tags. How can i get this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the option `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` when creating your regular expression.

HTH